# How to Pass a input field value from one form to another form in the different page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce checkout page form.
**for example. If the user fills the firstname field and lastname field
I am using custom button to redirect user to the new page from Woocommerce checkout page
In the new page there is also a new form
so I want the same fields should be auto filled like firstname and lastname**

My js for custom button

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#drittland").hide();
        /*jQuery(".woocommerce-checkout-payment").hide();*/
        var countryname = '';
        jQuery("#billing_country").change(function () {
        var countryname = jQuery('#billing_country').val();
            console.log(countryname);
                if ( countryname == "AT" || countryname == "BE" || countryname == "BG" || countryname == "HR" || countryname == "CY" || countryname == "CZ" || countryname == "DK" || countryname == "EE" || countryname == "FI" || countryname == "FR" || countryname == "DE" || countryname == "EL" || countryname == "HU" || countryname == "IE" || countryname == "IT" || countryname == "LV" || countryname == "LT" || countryname == "LU" || countryname == "MT" || countryname == "NL" || countryname == "PL" || countryname == "PT" || countryname == "RO" || countryname == "SK" || countryname == "SI" || countryname == "ES" || countryname == "SE" ) {
                    jQuery(".woocommerce-checkout-payment").show();
                    jQuery("#drittland").hide();
                } else {
                    jQuery(".woocommerce-checkout-payment").hide();
                    jQuery("#drittland").show();
                }
            });
    });
</script>
My function for custom button if functions.php file
```

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'return_to_cart_notice_button' );
function return_to_cart_notice_button(){

    ?><div class="registrition"><a href="redirection page link" id="drittland" class="button btn-v-dark">Drittland-Kunde Registrieren</a></div><?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the first form is complete you can store the name values that you want using localstorage and then add them to your second form.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30793071)